# Entity doesn't have fields required for Form Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have Entity:

```
public class User {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private String lastName;
  private String email;
  private String password;

  // getters and setters
}
```

I would like to use it as a Form Backing Object in presentation layer, but it doesn't have fields that I need. In this case I need repeatedPassword field. 
 
What is the best approach to this problem without modifying entity class? 
Should I extend this entity class and add needed fields? 
Should I create new class which has a field `private User user;` with getter and setter? 
Should I copy/paste this class and then add needed fields?

Comment: Inheriting it and adding the field required is the OOPS way to go about it.

Comment: IMO you should create a new class with all these fields and the extra ones. A Form Object is a Data Transfer Object. You will use it to transfer data between your layers or modules.

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem mapping this as a form-backing object. Just don't bind the repeatedPassword field, and validate that the repeated password matches in client-side Javascript.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Just out of curiosity, is there any advantage of creating a new class instead of inheriting it?

Comment: @JNL Absolutely none. It's just clearer to me what the intentions are if it's a separate object.

Comment: @Sotirios: i only meant, this repeatedPassword isn't anything that needs to go to the server, it should be used for local validation only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three different solutions:

- The usual way of dealing with a situation where the input fields on a form don't match up with an entity is to use a Command object (this is what Sotirios was advocating in the comments). Making a separate object for this that is not an entity is much less confusing than extending the entity to add something unrelated to persistence.
- It be argued in this case there's no need to pass the `repeatedPassword` field back to the server, the validation could be done entirely on the client, and the input field doesn't need to be bound to a Java pojo at all.
- If you really want to pass the `repeatedPassword` back to the server (so you can do all your validation on the server-- although the repeated password is more of a user convenience than real validation), then you could add the `repeatedPassword` field to the User entity with a @Transient declaration.